# How to use the eclipse for creating servlets

Tags: jakarta-ee

Usally i create the servlet class in the notepad and compile it using javac tool and then put the .class file in the classes directory inside WEB-INF folder.
and then create the war file of my web application and deployed it in the web logic server.

Now i want to deploy my web application inside eclipse. i have also read some of the similiar links [How to run servlets in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113497/how-to-run-servlets-in-eclipse).

But i have created a servlet class in the src directory in eclipse and also mapped my  the web.xml file in the WEB-INF folder. but i did not see any .class file in the classes folder when i run my application in the eclipse . please help me how to run the servlet using eclipse?
May you please guide me with steps to run the servlet code in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a server - Window > Show View > Servers. There is a wizard for defining a new server. Once you define a server you right click on it and you add the project to the server - then right click on the project and Run as > Run on server. Comment for details